# Gradle ant subproject dependency ordering

Tags: ant, gradle

I've got a project with 6 subprojects that have ant build.xml files in them.  I'm trying to write a top level gradle file that will do the ant 'default' task on all the projects, respecting their order dependencies.  So I have this in settings.gradle (which happens to be the order I want them run in):

```
include 'core', 'api-web', 'execution', 'cluster', 'persistence', 'choreo-tests'
```

And I have this in my top level build.gradle:

```
project(':api-web') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}

project(':execution') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':api-web')
    }
}

project(':cluster') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':execution')
    }
}

project(':persistence') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':cluster')
    }
}

project(':choreo-tests') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':persistence')
    }
}
```

And then each directory has this in its build.gradle:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

However, if I try to run this:

```
gradle --info default
```

I get this output:

```
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':core'] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@4d12bc7b.
```

I don't understand, since the build.xml files all have a compile target.  Is there something I need to do to have the ant build.xml files get loaded into their own namespace?

Or, more specifically, after having loaded these subprojects, which contain gradle tasks created from the ant targets, how can I specify the dependencies between subprojects tasks?  Every build.xml I have has a `'default'` task.  How do I specify that my `'default'` task in `project(':api-web')` depends on the `'default'` task of `project(':core')`?

Comment: There is no such thing as an execution order between Gradle projects (execution order is solely constrained by task relationships). An Ant target named `compile` will be mapped to a Gradle task named `compile`. This is not the same as a `compile` configuration. Gradle can infer task dependencies from project dependencies, but you won't get the necessary setup merely by importing Ant builds. From my experience, `ant.importBuild` isn't very useful in practice, and it's almost always better to bite the bullet and port the build.

Comment: Is what I have above a compile configuration?  So the compile statement above doesn't map to the compile task which was created from the ant target?  Looks like I have more documentation reading to do.  I was hoping to get the gradle build working via ant.importBuild and then port targets/tasks over piecemeal.  I had it working for just one subproject and was hoping it would be as easy for the others.

Comment: Maybe a better question would have been: After importing the various ant targets into gradle tasks, how can I specify the dependencies between those tasks?  For instance how to specify the default task of project(':api-web') depends on the default task of project(':core')?

Comment: The above adds project dependencies to compile *configurations* (which don't exist here). An idiomatic Gradle build looks very different from one created piecemeal by porting Ant targets to Gradle tasks. I don't think `ant.importBuild` turns default Ant targets into default Gradle tasks. (Gradle has a concept of default tasks, but it's not very commonly used.) Anyway, to make a task named `foo` in project `api-web` depend on a task named `bar` in project `core`, add the following to `api-web`'s build script: `foo.dependsOn(":core:bar")`.